# Google Maps with a Street View Mouse Over

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to ask if it would be possible/realistic to have a google map and then use a mouse over to show google street view in a seperate box?

eg: I have a google map of a Long/Lat created using standard syntax:

```
        var mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('divContainer'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37, 144),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            fullscreenControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false
        });
```

Then with the map a use could run the mouse over the map and see the street view if a box/div that either followed the mouse around of sat to the side etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a interesting use case. I think possible to do it.

You can do it with [**StreetViewPanorama class**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) - as a first argument you pass an HTML element that will be the container for the street view and the second one is the options([**StreetViewPanoramaOptions object**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions))

Then we need to capture the `mousemove` event when the mouse is over the map, get the [**LatLngBounds**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) of the cursor and update [**StreetViewPanorama**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) position with `setPosition()` method. If you want to somehow rotate the **point-of-view** while updating the position you can use `setPov()` method(*see StreetViewPanorama class*).

You can have another code that will take care to move the small street view window(*pano*), but this I leave to you :)

Let's have a look on the following example:

```js
function initialize() {
  var fenway = {
    lat: 42.345573,
    lng: -71.098326
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14
  });
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('pano'), {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10
      }
    });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    panorama.setPosition(e.latLng);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
}

.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize">
</script>

<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
```

Let me know if this works for you. This is just an idea to help you implement your specific use case and probably not the exactly right solution, but I hope you have a starting point now :)